# OpenFDA API for drug Label changes

Tags: data.gov, openfda, api, drugs

Is there is any API for getting the label changes for a list of drugs.

I have been searching for APIs and RSS feeds with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

As of right now, SPL (structured product labels) are not part of the openFDA list of APIs for drugs (https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/ - note how "product labels" is greyed out). You can learn more about the SPL standard, guidance, etc. directly from the FDA at http://www.fda.gov/ForIndustry/DataStandards/StructuredProductLabeling/default.htm.

---

While you wait for the openFDA project to serve SPLs, there is a robust (and actively improved - latest update was February 2014) website (with web services!) maintained by HHS/NIH/NLM called DailyMed. Information on DailyMed web services can be found at http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/help.cfm#webservices .

*From my intermediate knowledge of SPLs*, they are versioned by a unique GUID called "set IDs" as well as an addition "SPL version". There is an API endpoint for getting [the history of a specific SPL Set ID](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/help/spls_setid_history_api.cfm) as well as an [API endpoint for finding the drug record](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/help/spls_api.cfm) (including set ID) in the first place.

Also note that the DailyMed site maintains an RSS feed for each set ID (such as `http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/labelrss.cfm?setid=c5fdde91-1989-4dd2-9129-4f3323ea2962`) as well as an RSS feed for all changes in the past 7 days (`http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/rss.cfm`).

Hope this helps!